# Why aren't shoes, belt, and head covering included in the bracha of "Malbish Arumim?"

Tags: blessing, clothing, tractate-brachot, shoes

The **Shulchan Aruch** in [Orach Chaim 46:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.46.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (codifying the gemara on [Berachos 60b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) lists the morning brachos that one makes upon waking up.
Among them:

**Getting dressed**

> "כשלובש יברך "מלביש ערומים
>
> When he gets dressed, he blesses "Who clothes the naked."

This bracha would seem to cover one's clothes, yet 3 subsequent brachos **ALSO** seem to be about clothes:

**1) Putting on shoes**

> "כשנועל מנעליו יברך "שעשה לי כל צרכי
>
> When he puts on his shoes, "Who provides me with all of my needs."

**2) Putting on a belt**

> "כשחוגר חגורו יברך "אוזר ישראל בגבורה
>
> When he puts on a belt, "Who girds Israel with strength."

**3) Putting on a head covering**

> "כשמשים כובע או מצנפת בראשו יברך "עוטר ישראל בתפארה
>
> When he puts a hat or turban on his head, he blesses "Who crowns Israel with glory."

### Question

- Why are there a separate brachos for putting on shoes, belt and head covering- why aren't these included in the bracha for one's clothes?

Comment: I imagine the idea is that someone wearing clothes is not naked, even without shoes, belt or head covering. These items add further importance/dignity to the person, and are thus worthy of their own blessings.

Answer (score 1):

The shoes are the willing to go and accomplish mitzvoth.
The belt is the the unwavering link between Hashem and Am Israel.
The head covering is the crown of the Torah but also the way Am Israel makes Hashem "shine" in this world among the Nations (Kedushat Levy, Pessach' section).
That's why we need to make 3 separated brakhot.
For more details, please, take a look at the Yessod VeShoresh Haavodah, vol.1 from perek 3.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Why is the fact that a belt is the unwavering link between Hashem and Am Israel a reason for a separate brakha?

Comment: Please, for more informations, read **יסוד ושורש העבודה**.
It explains, in details, the how and the why of all our Avodaat Hashem and, specifically, for the morning brachots and this bracha.

Comment: @DoubleAA The reasons for the shoes and head covering you *are* good with?